# how do i get my gmail attachment in json format

Tags: c#, json, mime-types, attachment

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(class, Formatting.Indented);
var menstream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json));
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(menstream, new ContentType("application/json"));
attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Invoice.json";
```

I send mail from gmail with this. I am receiving the attachment as application-octect format. I need to get in `JSON` format.

Comment: Programming language used is c#

Comment: how to attach create a json file from a class and send it via gmail in MVC c#